# matching multiple dataframes colums to a main dataframe but not on found customers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following main dataframe for customer who purchased something for this month:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['cus1234', 'Sara'], ['cus12345', 'Kate'], ['cus994', 'Silvia'],['cus930', 'Fernando'],['cus098', 'Sherry'],['cus88332', 'Paul']]),

                   columns=['CustomerID', 'Name'])
```

df:

```
    CustomerID  Name
0   cus1234     Sara
1   cus12345    Kate
2   cus994     Silvia
3   cus930     Fernando
4   cus098      Sherry
5   cus88332    Paul
```

Each customerID is unique, now I have many more dataframes that contain customer information like email, country, phone, last purchase date and so on..

What I want to achieve is mapping the customer information to the current month customers who purchased something.

Suppose this is one of the dataframes:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['cus1234', 'Sara@example.com','Mexico'], ['cus9940', 'Howard@example.com','US'], ['cus994', 'Silvia@example.com','India'],['cus93000', 'rodri@example.com','UK'],['cus0900338', 'wez@example.com','US'],['cus88333132', 'deed@example.com','France'],['cust2020', 'ooops@example.com','Denmark'],['cus801033132', 'ooee2@example.com','Germany']]),

                   columns=['CustomerID', 'email','Country'])
```

df2:

```
   CustomerID                 email     Country
0   cus1234        Sara@example.com     Mexico
1   cus9940        Howard@example.com   US
2   cus994       Silvia@example.com     India
3   cus93000       rodri@example.com    UK
4   cus0900338      wez@example.com     US
5   cus88333132     deed@example.com    France
6   cust2020       ooops@example.com    Denmark
7   cus801033132    ooee2@example.com   Germany
```

Now I did the matching using `merge` on the original dataframe, so two customers are matched and others replaced with `NaN`:

```
df.merge(df2, on='CustomerID', how='left')
```

result:

```
    CustomerID  Name      email                Country
0   cus1234     Sara       Sara@example.com     Mexico
1   cus12345    Kate        NaN                  NaN
2   cus994     Silvia      Silvia@example.com   India
3   cus930     Fernando     NaN                  NaN
4   cus098      Sherry      NaN                  NaN
5   cus88332    Paul        NaN                  NaN
```

Another dataframe that has customer information that I matched with merge but the results now come with more columns_x or _y, I need to match on the previous matched dataframe `NaNs`:

df3:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['cus1245534', 'orego@example.com','Brazil'], ['cus930', 'fernandino@example.com','US'], ['cus93394', 'test@example.com','India'],['cus88332', 'paul33@example.com','UK'],['cus011338', 'dumm@example.com','US'],['cus800033132', 'dumm3@example.com','France']]),

                   columns=['CustomerID', 'email','Country'])
```

Matching results:

[image]

How can I automate all matching process in the same columns and not to search for already matched customers?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to concatenate `df2` and `df3` before doing the merge, you can rename columns in `df3`, and use `fillna` to "complete" the search.

```
df_search1 = df.merge(df2, on='CustomerID', how='left')
df_search2 = df_search1.merge(df3.rename(columns = {'email':'email2', 'Country':'Country2'}, how = 'left', on = 'CustomerID')
df_search2['email'] = df_search2['email'].fillna(df_search2['email2'])
df_search2['Country'] = df_search2['Country'].fillna(df_search2['Country2'])
df_search2.drop(['email2', 'Country2'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thank you, this exactly did what I want but what if dataframes have many many columns for matching, is there another way for merging? concatenation is not possible